# Multiple event bindings is not working on dynamic content

Tags: jquery, events

I have a "input field component" like:

```
<div class="input-multilingual multilingual-field">
   <div class="input-multilingual-prepend">
        <input type="text" value="" name="nameVariants[0].texts[nl_BE]">
    </div>
   <div class="input-multilingual-prepend">
        <input type="text" value="" name="nameVariants[0].texts[en_GB]">
    </div>
</div>
```

Which I have attached a focus/blur event to this, which works on page load:

```
$(".multilingual-field").on({
        focus: function() {
            $(this).parents(".multilingual-field").addClass("focus");
        },
        blur: function() {
            $(this).parents(".multilingual-field").removeClass("focus");
        }
    }, ":input");
```

The problem is that this is enclosed in a `div`, which content is re-rendered by AJAX once a new "input field component" is added. After that action the focus/blur method is not working anymore.

I thought by adding the `":input"` as an argument on the `.on(...)`, this would work with dynamic content? What am I missing?

**Update**

It seems like if I listen on `$(document).on({...}, ".multilingual-field :input")` it works - why is this? :-)

Comment: Looks like you've answered your own question. In your update, it works like that because that's the [expected usage](http://api.jquery.com/on/) of the `on()` function. You're delegating the same event to each descendant of `document` that matches the `:input` selector, which sounds like exactly what you needed.

Comment: You have an element(s) with a class of multilingual-field which also have parents with class multilingual-field?  I believe that's what your JS says but your HTML says something different.

Answer (score 0):

Event handlers in jQuery are attached to specific DOM node on execution of "on" function. When DOM node is removed and recreated it is loosing its event listeners.

Use "live" function instead.

```
$(".multilingual-field").live("focus",
        function() {
            $(this).parents(".multilingual-field").addClass("focus");
        }
);
```